# Перестал запускаться ПК по ошбике : не видит диск

Tags: windows

Пробовал сбросить биос до заводских настроек, и до оптимальных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой смысл сбрасывать БИОС? Проблема скорее всего железная. Контакты кабеля (кабель-мать либо кабель-диск), контакты питания, или даже просто неисправность диска (да, они иногда дохнут). И фотография сделана поздновато (а по-хорошему надо было фотать экран настроек БИОС на странице. где перечислены жёсткие диски).

Comment: проблема с диском (либо с шиной диска на материнку) попробуй другой диск установить и запустить .